# Menu works perfectly in Safari but not Chrome?

Tags: html, css, webflow

I am having trouble figuring out why my site menu shows up differently over browsers. Screenshots are below.

[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IAm1.png)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNhb3.jpg)

Site is [here](https://terrancemcarthur.webflow.io/).

Update: Figured out what is causing it. It’s these lines of code in the head. Still unsure why it would mess up the menu in chrome but not safari.

```
<style>
.navigation { 
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you upload the photo of how it shows on Safari? But you're using ``webkit`` so I don't think there would be a problem with chrome.

Comment: Hi @AmirrezaAmini just uploaded the screenshots. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: But I don't think that ``backdrop-filter`` is related to this kind of problem. I mean you're applying blur, why would be there a problem with how it shows the navbar?

Comment: i think the problem is connected to z index more than to filter

Comment: That's why I am so confused. If I remove that code the menu works exactly as it should in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this.

```
.full-screen-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Good luck Mr. McArthur!

Comment: and you can disable ``z-index``. No need to use it.

Comment: That did it! Silly mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Accept this answer I need reputation lol.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow haha